# How can I remove width and height from the <img> tag?

Tags: theming

Does anybody know how to remove width and height from this HTML markup?

```html
<img src="/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/2016-03/
dummy-640x480.jpg?itok=9_RdHYGq" alt="mein dummie" typeof="foaf:Image"
class="img-responsive" width="480" height="360">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your theme open file THEMENAME.theme, example in my case THEMENAME is bartik and file is bartik.theme add code below:

```
function bartik_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['attributes']['width']) && isset($variables['attributes']['height'])) {
    unset($variables['attributes']['width']);
    unset($variables['attributes']['height']);
  }
}
```

Clear all cache and see result.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_image().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['style_name'] == 'IMAGE_STYLE_NAME') {
    // Remove explicit width & height declaration.
    unset($vars['width'], $vars['height'], $vars['attributes']['width'], $vars['attributes']['height']);
  }
}
```

Comment: `hook_preprocess_image()` doesn't normally get the style name, in its array parameter. That is a value `hook_preprocess_image_style()` gets and passes to `hook_preprocess_image()`. Since the first isn't necessarily invoked from the latter, this is the less generic code.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to solve this inside a twig template you can use the following:

```
<img{{ attributes.addClass(classes).removeAttribute('width').removeAttribute('height') }} />
```

This should be available since Drupal 8, see following issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2325517